# Docker Desktop on Mac - won't update

Tags: mac, docker

I have docker desktop installed on my mac.  I'm trying to update it but I've run into a snag.  Not sure if it's related but the only thing that's different about my install is that the application is running on the SDD but ... the data has been configured to live on an external drive as depicted below:

[[image]a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiUPu.jpg)

When I try to "Update and restart" i see that the icon in the system tray shows it's doing something. But eventually the exclamation mark returns and this is what I see in the menu:

[image]

But it never does update.
I've also tried restarting my mac. But the system doesn't update it.  I'm still running desktop version 3.3.3

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found this post:  https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5677

And so I basically stopped and restarted the application multiple times before the update actually worked.

Unlike previous attempts when I requested the download, after the multiple restarts, it asked me for my admin account on the mac to allow the app to change my system.